# How do I process this array to get this result?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array,

```
      array (size=6)
      0 => 
      array (size=6)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'member_ext' => string '1' (length=1)
      'queue_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'LastUpdate' => string '2013-10-24' (length=10)
      'member_name' => string 'John Smith' (length=10)
      'queue_name' => string 'queue 1' (length=7)
      1 => 
      array (size=6)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'member_ext' => string '2' (length=1)
      'queue_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'LastUpdate' => string '2013-10-24' (length=10)
      'member_name' => string 'Jose Jones' (length=10)
      'queue_name' => string 'queue 1' (length=7)
      2 => 
      array (size=6)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'member_ext' => string '1' (length=1)
      'queue_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'LastUpdate' => string '2013-10-24' (length=10)
      'member_name' => string 'John Smith' (length=10)
      'queue_name' => string 'queue 1' (length=7)
      3 => 
      array (size=6)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'member_ext' => string '3' (length=1)
      'queue_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'LastUpdate' => string '2013-10-24' (length=10)
      'member_name' => string 'Mary Chase' (length=10)
            'queue_name' => string 'queue 2' (length=7)
      4 => 
      array (size=6)
      'id' => string '7' (length=1)
      'member_ext' => string '3' (length=1)
      'queue_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'LastUpdate' => string '2013-10-24' (length=10)
      'member_name' => string 'Mary Chase' (length=10)
      'queue_name' => string 'queue 3' (length=7)
      5 => 
      array (size=6)
      'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'member_ext' => string '4' (length=1)
      'queue_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'LastUpdate' => string '2013-10-24' (length=10)
      'member_name' => string 'Fred Allen' (length=10)
      'queue_name' => string 'queue 4' (length=7)
```

How can I use php to get it into an html table like this? "logged in" meaning they're were found in the array as beining logged into a particular queue, "logged out" meaning the tech wasn't not found in that particulat queue.

```
| techs     | queue 1    | queue 2    | queue 3    | queue 4    | queue 5    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|John Smith | logged in  | logged in  | logged out | logged out | logged out |
|Jose Jones | logged in  | logged out | logged out | logged out | logged out |
|Mary Case  | logged out | logged out | logged in  | logged out | logged out |
|Fred Allen | logged out | logged out | logged out | logged in  | logged out |
```

EDIT - THIS IS WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR.

```
    <?php
    try {
$username = "admin";
//$password = "TrojanF32";
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $username);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "connected<p>";
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT queue_name
FROM `log`
WHERE LastUpdate = '2013-10-24'
ORDER BY queue_name ASC
");
$sth->execute();
$sql1 = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * 
FROM `log`
WHERE LastUpdate = '2013-10-24'
ORDER BY queue_name ASC
");
$sth->execute();
$sql2 =$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?><div class="container"><?php

echo "<table border=1>";
echo  "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "Technician" . "</td>";
foreach($sql1 as $header){
echo "<td>" . $header['queue_name'] . "</td>";  
}
echo "</tr>";

foreach($sql2 as $queue){
    echo "<td>" . $queue['member_name'] . "</td>";
    //echo "<td>";
    foreach($queue as $que){

        if($queue['queue_id'] == '1'){
            echo "<td>" . "logged in" . "</td>";
        }else{
            echo "<td>" . "logged out" . "</td>";
            }
        if($queue['queue_id'] == '2'){
            echo "<td>" . "logged in" . "</td>";
        }else{
            echo "<td>" . "logged out" . "</td>";
            }
        if($queue['queue_id'] == '3'){
            echo "<td>" . "logged in" . "</td>";
        }else{
            echo "<td>" . "logged out" . "</td>";
            }
        if($queue['queue_id'] == '4'){
            echo "<td>" . "logged in" . "</td>";
        }else{
            echo "<td>" . "logged out" . "</td>";
            }
        if($queue['queue_id'] == '5'){
            echo "<td>" . "logged in" . "</td>";
        }else{
            echo "<td>" . "logged out" . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($sql2);
echo "</pre>";




?>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: Show us the code you've already tried.

Comment: what have you tried ? where is your current code ? how do you know if a user is logged in/out ?

Comment: Edited, sorry, frustration levels very higher with myself right now. posted in a fit of anger and desperation.

Comment: If I change your approuch with a modification on your second sql command would be better for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need just the queues and techs names I would chang a bit your code so See if this would help you.

I don't have an php enviroment to check, so, maybe you can find some syntax bugs. The real thing is to add a third query to get every one with every queue like I did here [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4afea/27)

So, let see:

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT queue_name
                      FROM `log`
                      WHERE LastUpdate = '2013-10-24'
                      ORDER BY queue_name ASC");
$sth->execute();
$sql1 = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT member_name
                      FROM `log`
                      WHERE LastUpdate = '2013-10-24'
                      ORDER BY member_name ASC");
$sth->execute();
$sql2 = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sth = $dbh->prepare("select ml.member_name, ml.queue_name,
        case ifnull(l.id,-1) when -1 then 'Logging Out' else 'Logging In' end as logstatus
   from (select l1.member_name, l2.queue_name 
           from (select distinct member_name from `log` where lastupdate='2013-10-24') l1,
                (select distinct queue_name from `log` where lastupdate='2013-10-24') l2
         ) ml 
         left join 
         (select * from `log` where LastUpdate='2013-10-24') as l 
         on ( ml.member_name = l.member_name and ml.queue_name = l.queue_name )
 order by ml.member_name, ml.queue_name");
$sth->execute();
$sql3 = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<div class="container">
<?php
echo "<table border=1>";
echo  "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "Technician" . "</td>";
foreach($sql1 as $header){
    echo "<td>" . $header['queue_name'] . "</td>";  
}
echo "</tr>";

foreach($sql2 as $names){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $names['member_name'] . "</td>";
    foreach($sql3 as $queues){
        if ( $names['member_name'] == $queues['member_name'] ){
            echo "<td>" . $queues['logstatus'] . "</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</div>
```

Let me know if you encounter any problem with this code.

Comment: of course that is the easiest way... With just the query I created you could print the entire table with some logic

Comment: That worked great! Thank you so much, I've learned something!